Manga where the male and female leads are rivals who have reincarnated multiple times, but in this particular reincarnation they are in high school
I cannot remember much about this mostly black & white manga, aside from the basic knowledge that they were rivals who reincarnated constantly trying to kill each other. But I do remember that the manga begins when they're both high school students going to the same school. The setting is a normal high school in Japan and only the two main characters have the ability to reincarnate; everyone else is just normal.

Was this full colour or mostly black & white? And was the MC male?

It was mostly black & white, and the mc was male.

Are you sure the two protagonists were reincarnated multiple times? I found a manga that seems quite similar, but the protagonists were only reincarnated once, after fighting many times in their previous life.

I think that might be it.

Any idea if they end up getting together romantically after reincarnating? i.e. is this an enemies-to-lovers story, or do they continue being rivals in high school?

These both have multiple reincarnators (more than 2) so I assume it isn't either of these, but could you explicitly rule out Bokura no Kiseki and Tensei Yuusha wa Joshikousei!?: Maou no Dekiai ni Komattemasu? Latter is a demon lord and hero repeatedly reincarnating, but the hero's other party members reincarnate as well.

Maybe Spirit Circle?
It fits with both the normal school setting and only the two main characters being aware of their reincarnations (although the side characters do show up in their previous lifes).

Synopsis
Fuuta Okeya, a 14-year-old student, can see ghosts and wears a bandage on his left cheek to hide his striking birthmark. One day, a girl with a scar on her forehead named Kouko Ishigami, accompanied by a ghost of a tall and friendly man, transfers into his class.


Fuuta quickly takes a liking to Kouko, wondering if it might be love at first sight. After waking up crying from a strange dream involving her, he feels a nostalgic connection to Kouko and becomes determined to befriend her. However, a chain of events forces Fuuta to reveal his birthmark to Kouko, to which she declares him to be the enemy of her life. A furious Kouko explains that the two are bound by reincarnation, and that Fuuta's birthmark is a curse she engraved on him in one of their past lives to recognize and eventually defeat him.


Kouko brings out a circular object made of flames known as the "spirit circle" and attacks Fuuta, pushing him off a flight of stairs. As he falls, Fuuta is thrown back into the insight of one of his previous lives. Spirit Circle chronicles Fuuta's journey back and forth his several past lives as he gradually unravels the mysteries behind his apparent bad blood with Kouko.


Yes, that's it, thank you so much.

@user174400 no problem, dont forget to mark the answer as correct.

Is this Reincarnated - The Hero Marries the Sage ~After Becoming Engaged to a Former Rival, We Became the Strongest Couple~...?
From Anime-Planet:

Reid, a young hero with the strongest physical strength, and Elria, a beautiful sage with the strongest magic prowess. They continued to fight as rivals in opposing enemy nations, but their relationship came to an end with the sudden death of Elria…Then, a thousand years later, reincarnated in a world where magic reigns supreme, but he who has retained the strongest physical strength from his previous life, Reid, was reunited with Elria, who has also been reincarnated ――

In the first chapter, we're introduced to the titular Hero, Reid Frieden of the Altien Empire, and the Sage, Elria Caldwen of Vegalta. The Altien Empire and Vegalta were at war with one another for over 50 years, and so Reid and Elria fought one another over 6000 times during that period, each being the strongest combatant on their respective sides. Despite this, they're portrayed as friendly rivals who enjoyed competing with one another, and when an elderly Reid learned that Elria had finally died of illness, he singlehandedly fought his way to the Vegalta Royal Capital, with no armour or weapons, just to pay his respects to her in person. In doing so, he sustained grievous injuries and died shortly afterwards himself.



He's then reincarnated 1000 years later as a villager in what is now known as the Vegalta Magic Kingdom, after the Altien Empire was absorbed into Vegalta. At the age of 18, he's told that he's been summoned by a high-ranking noble, and when he meets her, it turns out she's Elria, who's also been reincarnated and had been searching for him. They immediately recognise one another, as they remember their previous lives, and also seemingly look much the same as they did before (except that Elria is now human, rather than an elf), as well as having the same names as before. Since they're no longer on opposing sides, she proposes that they become engaged and invites him to come to the capital to enrol in the Royal Magic Academy with her. He accepts and they take entrance exams and enrol at the academy in chapter 4.




No, the setting is in a normal highschool in Japan, only the two main characters have the ability to reincarnate, everyone else is just normal.
